# Expected number of attempts to get 2 out of 50 results at least once?

Tags: probability

I looked at some material, such as markov chains and inclusion-exclusion, but was unable to wrap my head around them with my only cursory understanding of probability.

I'm trying to find the solution to a problem where there are 50 possible unique results of equal probability; you could imagine a deck of cards with the one-eyed jacks removed. **How many times do I have to draw, with replacement, before I draw both two-eyed jacks (which are also replaced) at least once?**

---

My initial intuition is that we can start with an expected 100 attempts, because it is $1/p$ or **50 expected attempts** for the first jack and then you have the same deck you started with for **+50 expected attempts** for the other jack, but I suspect that I need to subtract some amount for the chance that the second jack was already drawn before the first.

I also tried to do what [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1793530/537784) suggests and treated the problem like a 3-sided die where... $$p(1) = 48/50\qquad p(2) = p(3) = 1/50$$ 
...treating the **1-result** as every other card in the deck, and the **2-result** and **3-result** as the desired draws. This, I guess, gives me an expected outcome of... $$4H_4-\frac{48}{50}\cdot4$$

...but I don't know how to account for the **0.04%** chance that I get the **2-result** and **3-result** right away. That alone wouldn't be a problem as I doubt it changes the expected number of draws enough to matter, but I also don't know what $H_4$ means to do the calculation.

**Any help you can offer to complete either of my two approaches (or to enlighten me on why these approaches don't work for my question) would be greatly appreciated.**

---

I looked at these related questions, but the methods don't seem to work for this problem since they want each result at least once, and I only want two results (or perhaps I just don't understand the answers well enough to apply them to my question):

- [Expected number of trials before I get one of each type](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1660538/537784)
- [Expected number of rolls for an unfair die to get all possibile values at least once](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1793253/537784)

Comment: For anyone wondering, the application of this question is related to D&D and trying to find the expected number of Wild Magic Surges before two desired outcomes are reached. Related to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/168037/41726) on RPG StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3618512/357390). For this question, at the start, the probability of drawing the first (as yet undetermined) two-eyed jack is $\frac2{50}$, so $\frac{50}2$ draws are expected to get it; once that has been drawn, there is a $\frac1{50}$ chance of drawing the other two-eyed jack, so $\frac{50}1$ draws are expected to get it. The expected total number of draws is then their sum: $\frac{50}2+\frac{50}1=75$.

In general, if you are waiting for $k$ specific results from repeating a draw on $n$ objects with replacement, the expected number of draws needed is $n\sum_{i=1}^k\frac1i$.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Yeah, sorry, I might make these silly mistakes from time to time. It's been corrected.